WS28213B Loop 241230
Hello Stack Exchange Arduino,
Running LED strip WS2812B using
Arduino compatible SEEED XIAO SAM D21
microcontroller.

Code marked
"WS2812b_turn_on_and_off_w_for_241230_ino"copied
herewith below, turns on all strip LEDs in twp
colors for a second and a half, then turns the LEDs
off for one tenth of a second.
These two phases begin when the PCB is powered
and continues going on and off until power
is disconnected
Code marked
"WS2812b_move_three_241230.ino" also copied
below, chases groups of three LEDs across
the strip once and stops.
It was expected that the Move Three function
would repeat because it is in the void Loop()
section but it only runs once.
Why does the Move Three function not loop?
Thanks.
Allen Pitts
++++++++++ WS2812b_turn_on_and_off_w_for_241230_ino  +++++++++
#include <FastLED.h>

#define LED_PIN     3
#define NUM_LEDS    150

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, LED_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
} 

void loop() {
 // for (int i = 0; i < 146; i = i + 2) {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 146; i = i + 2) { 
    // turn on
    leds[i] = CRGB(255,160,16);
    // Show the leds
    FastLED.show();
    //delay(50);
  }

  for (int i = 1; i <= 146; i = i + 2) { 
    // turn on
   leds[i] = CRGB(0, 255, 0);
    // Show the leds
  FastLED.show();
//delay(50);
 }

   delay(1500);

  for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
    // turn off 
    leds[i] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
    // Show the leds
    FastLED.show();
   // delay(10);

  }
}

++++++++++ end of WS2812b_turn_on_and_off_w_for_241230_ino  +++++++++
++++++++++ WS2812b_move_three_241230.ino  +++++++++
#include <FastLED.h>

#define DATA_PIN    3
#define NUM_LEDS    150
#define BRIGHTNESS  10
#define LED_TYPE    WS2812B
#define COLOR_ORDER GRB

// Define the array of leds
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

#define UPDATES_PER_SECOND 100

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE, DATA_PIN, COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  FastLED.setBrightness(BRIGHTNESS);
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
    leds[i]     = CRGB::Red;
    leds[i + 1] = CRGB::Green;
    leds[i + 2] = CRGB::Blue;
    FastLED.show();
    delay(.9);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
      leds[i] = CRGB::Black;
      delay(.7);
    }
  }
}

++++++++++ end of WS2812b_move_three_241230.ino  +++++++++

Please give a detailed description of what you expected to happen and what actually happened. Ther is so move three function in the second code. And what does the first code have to do with your question?

put the programming ideas from the first sketch in your second sketch ... increment the for loop by three ... correct the delay(.9); and delete everything after it
